# CA2000 object 'comm' is not disposed along all exception paths

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a bunch of methods like so in my DAL in VS 2010. When I run the "new" Code Analysis option i get the message - Warning   CA2000  object 'comm' is not disposed along all exception paths. Call System.IDisposable.Dispose on object 'comm' before all references to it are out of scope.

I understand I could use another using statement for the SQLCommand however if prefer to do it like I have with the Try/Finally block. My understanding is the Finally block executes last and does the cleanup. Does anyone see anything wrong here with my dispose call?

```
  public List<Product> GetAllProducts()
    {

        List<Product> prodList = new List<Product>();
        using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(GetConnection()))
        {
            SqlCommand comm = new SqlCommand("GetAllProducts", connection);
            connection.Open();
            comm.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            SqlDataReader dr = comm.ExecuteReader();
            try
            {
                while (dr.Read())
                {
                    Product obj = new Product();
                    obj.ProductID = Convert.ToInt32(dr["ProductID"].ToString());
                    obj.Product = dr["Product"].ToString();
                    //etc....                                                                       

                    prodList.Add(obj);
                }
            }
            finally
            {
                comm.Dispose();
                dr.Close();
            }
        }

        return prodList;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

If any of these three statements throw an exception, `comm` will not be disposed.

```
        connection.Open();
        comm.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        SqlDataReader dr = comm.ExecuteReader();
```

Your try block would need to encompas these statements as well.

Comment: If i do this then i have to remove the dr.cose() out of the finally block because I get an error message "The name dr does not exist in the current context". Does this make sense? I just thought I would want the dr.close to be specifically in the finally block in the event of an error..

Comment: You have two different objects you need to dispose, and these are allocated on different lines. This means you either need to use two try/finally blocks or you need to initialize one of them to null and make sure it is not null before calling dispose.

Comment: I dont think I have ever seen 2 Try finally blocksand does not sound correct to me. I just implemented the using (SqlCommand comm = new SqlCommand("GetAllProducts", connection)) and the Code Analysis still says 
 "call System.IDisposable.Dispose on object 'comm' before all references to it are out of scope." and 
 call System.IDisposable.Dispose on object 'connection' before all references to it are out of scope.

Answer (score 1):

Put a using block around the command and dataReader so that they will always be disposed.

```
public List<Product> GetAllProducts()
{
    List<Product> prodList = new List<Product>();
    using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(GetConnection()))
    {
        using (SqlCommand comm = new SqlCommand("GetAllProducts", connection))
        {
            connection.Open();
            comm.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            using (SqlDataReader dr = comm.ExecuteReader())
            {
                try
                {
                    while (dr.Read())
                    {
                        Product obj = new Product();
                        obj.ProductID = Convert.ToInt32(dr["ProductID"].ToString());
                        obj.Product = dr["Product"].ToString();
                        //etc....                                                                       

                        prodList.Add(obj);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    return prodList;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
        List<Measure_Type> MeasureList = new List<Measure_Type>();
        SqlConnection conn = null;            

        SqlDataReader rdr = null;
        SqlCommand cmd = null;
        try
        {
            conn = new SqlConnection();
            conn.ConnectionString = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Conn"];
            conn.Open();
            cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT Measure_ID, Mea_Name FROM MeasureTable WHERE IsActive=1", conn);

            rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
            if (rdr.HasRows == true)
            {
                while (rdr.Read())
                {
                    MeasureTypeList.Add(new Measure_Type { MeasureTypeID = Convert.ToInt32(rdr[0]), MeasureTypeName = rdr[1].ToString() });
                }
            }
        }

        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            ExceptionPolicy.HandleException(ex, "Log");
        }
        finally
        {
            cmd.Dispose();
            // close the reader
            if (rdr != null) { rdr.Close(); }
            // Close the connection
            if (conn != null) { conn.Dispose(); }
        }
        return MeasureTypeList;
```

create `conn = new SqlConnection();` inside the try block and then open it to solve this bug.